# mvc 4 pass textbox value to jquery object

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, textbox, parameter-passing

Sorry its me again the same DataFilter guy now with a different problem though :)

I can't seem to do a simple thing

```
var datafilterModel = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(new DataFilterModel("CustomerName", "string", "Mehdy"))) // This works perfect
```

Now I want to pass values from textbox instead of hardcoding. How would I do that? I tried below but I get error:

```
var datafilterModel = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(new DataFilterModel("CustomerName", "string", $('#textFilterValue').val()))) // Too many characters in the literal
```

Anyone save me time please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using server side helpers to generate the value of the `datafilterModel` javascript variable you can only pass the value of the textbox at the time the page was rendered on the server. If the user later changes this value for obvious reasons (and as explained to you in your previous questions) you will need to use only javascript to manipulate the value of this variable and not rely on any server side helpers. So assuming that this textbox is bound to some model value:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.TextFilterValue)
```

You can then pass the value like this:

```
var datafilterModel = @Html.Raw(
    Json.Encode(
        new DataFilterModel("CustomerName", "string", Model.TextFilterValue)
    )
);
```

If you want to achieve some dynamic binding to the value of the textbox you will have to use javascript. For example you can subscribe to the `onchange` event of this textbox and then manipulate the value:

```
$('#textFilterValue').change(function() {
    var filterValue = $(this).val();
    // here you can update the value of the datafilterModel javascript variable
});
```

The way to update the `datafilterModel` variable will depend on its structure. For example if this is a javascript object that looks like this:

```
var datafilterModel = { "Foo": "Bar", "Baz": "Bazinga" };
```

if you wanted to update the value of the `Baz` property you would use could simply assign it the new value:

```
$('#textFilterValue').change(function() {
    var filterValue = $(this).val();
    datafilterModel.Baz = filterValue;
});
```